# MYSQL csv filename to table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to search a folder and grab a file name to convert into a mysql table? Can it be done in a query or stored procedures?

I'm new to mysql and so far I can read my data and create a table which is manually done, but don't know how to create a table with its file name automatically.

```
LOAD DATA 
LOCAL INFILE 'D:/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible for LOAD DATA to create the table for you. The syntax for the function goes as ...

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    **INTO TABLE tbl_name**
```

The table name has to be specified, which means you have to create the table first.

Why is it so?
There are so many different data types that are supported in a mysql table that the importer is unable to judge for itself which data type to use.
Fro example if the first line in the CSV was

> hello, 1

The importer might choose CHAR(5) and INT but the next line might be

> Colombo, Galle

This line cannot be imported into CHAR(5) or INT

Comment: ok, so it is impossible to write a stored procedure that will read the contents of a specified folder and insert filenames into a table. right?

Comment: Impossible is a bit strong. If you already have the table created, it becomes quite easy. If you know what the table structure ought to be it's still possible.

Comment: actually, table is created already. I just want to match the filename in the server and update the corresponding table in the database.

Comment: In that case it's quite easy. But this is a job that can be more easily done ina  scripting language than a stored procedure.

Comment: I'm using asp.net to do that. What are the possible steps to implement that?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this site. You can ask a separate question for that but I doubt very much if you will get an answer. You will probably get a lot of down votes!

Comment: Since you are a new user, permit me to also point out that it's customary here to mark an answer as accepted if it answers the original question. That's because people who land here in the future will now what to do. And besides, we both get brownie points!

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your question with `mysql-workbench`, even though you don't ask about this tool. But let me tell that MySQL Workbench indeed can be of help here. In the SQL IDE which opens when you click on a connection tile on the homescreen you can use the context menu in the sidebar to open the table data import wizard. This will help you to import CSV (or JSON) data from a file and will also create the target table for you (if you don't pick an existing one).